# How to compare a .startIndex of Range<String.Index>

Tags: string, swift, nsstring, range, nsrange

I'm receiving a Range String.Index from the rangeOfString-method.

```
searchParagraphs = ress.rangeOfString("\n")
```

now i want to proof the position of the startIndex:

```
if searchParagraphs?.startIndex == 0 {}
```

it's not working, because *"String.Index? does not conform to protocol _RawOptionSetType"*. so how can i proof the position/startIndex of a String.Index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for the initial position, the correct way is:

```
if searchParagraphs?.startIndex == ress.startIndex {}
```